# Launching Facebook URL scheme fb//pages?id= not working

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I have a `UITableview` and on selection of a row I'm opening a link that looks something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow
```

If I open this link from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` the link opens in a Safari (when FB app is not opened) and opens in Fb app (if FB app is installed). When opened in safari the page is seen.

The url is opened using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]
```

When opened in fb app it takes me to my Facebook news feed. May I know if this is a default behavior? Do I need to configure the URL in this case?

**Update**
I tried using the URL: `fb//pages?id=11239244970`

```
 NSURL * fbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb//pages?id=11239244970"];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

It still didn't help. I might be missing something.

Two things happened:

1. using https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow works only if the FB app is not installed. If the app is installed it opens the FB app, and doesn't take you to the page.
2. When using the URL scheme,the fb app opens and displays news feed. (Expected to display Facebook page for stackoverflow)

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand you. Do you say that the link automatically opens in the Facebook app, from Safari? Can you explain in a bit more details exactly all the steps and your UI interactions?

Using specific FB urls to open certain pages is not supported.

Comment: @Roemer I updated the steps